# How to skip some Javascript events?

Tags: javascript, performance, events, dom

If you bind "mouseover" event for each table cell and move mouse from one corner to another - each event processed.

Usually event perform some visualization. If you move mouse fast I think there are no reason to drown in event handler on each element. Only on last where mouse stop.

But I don't understand how this can be achieved...

Comment: there are lots of ways, what have you tried? are you using jquery?

Comment: Simple approach: Delay the heavy execution (your visualization) for like 0.5s. If in this half second another event is triggered, remove the before queued operation and replace it by the new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something to debounce your events (that is, ignore all events that occur close to eachother except for the last one), or something to throttle your events.

You can achieve this by using timeouts in your event handlers, such that they don't proceed if the event was raised within the last 100ms, for example.

There are [ready-made solutions for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/) out there, and [Mootools More has a whole chunk of psuedo-events](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Class/Events.Pseudos) that will help you achieve the same thing.

Comment: Why not use the native `stop()` function for jQuery?

Comment: @Phil `stop` is for animations, not sure if that's the case here. And the question doesn't mention jQuery.

Comment: It will stop mouseover events from firing in progression though as the mouseover animation will be stopped and a new event will be fired.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I miss concepts about debounce or delaying actual action to skip previous which too near to each other!

Answer (score 3):

Use a timer to delay the action, and cancel the timer when apropriate:

```
var timer;
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].onmouseover = function() {
        var div = this;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7uRV/

Comment: Thanks, I will use this technique!